# Getting adjustment amount in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

I need to get the amount of a discount from orders to write that data into a json file (on EVENT_AFTER_COMPLETE_ORDER) which then will be consumed by an inventory management system and now am stuck with discount amounts. Currently I have:

```
"price": ' . $order->adjustment->one->type('discount')->amount . ',
```

which does not work. Could anyone help on how to do this and maybe point me to the documentation where I could read up on it?

Thanks
m

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
"price": ' . $order->totalDiscount . ',
```

^^